# How to use xsd schema definition

Tags: c#, .net, sql, xml

I am extracting data using a SQL statement in a C# console application. For example :

```
SELECT NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH FROM CUSTOMER_DETAIL
```

I then save it to xml.

The xml has two elements.  One is NAME and the second one is DATE_OF_BIRTH.  When I load them back into MS-SQL Server the DATE_OF_BIRTH column becomes varchar, but I would like to keep it smalldatetype in xml by defining xml schema.

I use GetXml() method to save in xml.

```
cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)  #a function that gives an association between two vectors                  
outer(mtcars, mtcars, "cor") #the attempt to create a matrix of all vectors in a df
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an xsd for the table, you want to save data as xml.

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Load the xsd in dataset.

```
 ds.ReadXmlSchema(xsdPath);
```

Now Read data in ds from sql server.

```
ds.WriteXml(xmlFullPath);
```

In this way, you will be able to save the data in proper format.